# How to dynamically add suggestions (views) and be able to control the textView in it

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment in my app that is a basic chatbot. For that chatbot, I want to be able to serve suggestions of replies the user can reply.

[image]

I have layout of the reply I want in an xml file.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/suggestion_border"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_suggestion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/chat_text_color"
        android:text="Suggestion"/>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

While produces something like this

[image]

and I have a incoming_msg.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_message"
    // irrelevent
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_time"
    // irrelevent
    android:text="12:90 PM"
    android:textColor="#b4b2b2"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/chat_time">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/suggestion_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And because the conversation fragment is a recycler view. I have a `onBindViewHolder`

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 1:
                IncomingMsg iM = (IncomingMsg) holder;
                iM.msg.setText(msg.get(position).getMessage());
                iM.dt.setText(df.format(msg.get(position).getTime()));


                if (!msg.get(position).getSuggest().isEmpty()) {
                    if (iM.s.getChildCount() != msg.get(position).getSuggest().size()) {
                        for (Suggestion tempSuggestion: msg.get(position).getSuggest()) {
                            if (tempSuggestion.isWithImage()) {
                                // TODO
                            } else {
                                iM.s.addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.outgoing_suggestion, iM.p));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

And at this point, I do not know how to continue, as I couldn't be able to scroll the suggestion list sideway and I couldn't control the text shown in the suggestion.

Comment: Have a recyclerview instead of scroll view.

Comment: 01 - Create an adapter recyclerview.
02 - And give a recyclerview that has its layoutmanager configured horizontally.
03 - Provide the text you want to display to the adapter and display in the recyclerview.
04 - For this adapter, consider a onclick interface property, and when it is clicked on the text, send it to the original recyclerview or to the server